# Ubuntu One repeatedly crashes on Android 2.2 (ZTE Blade)

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-one, android

Whenever my Android goes to sleep and disconnects the wifi to save power and then rewakes and reconnects to wifi, then my ubuntu-one-app is crashing with the following screen (translated from German)

we are sorry.
The application Ubuntu One Files (Process com.ubuntuone.android.files) was terminated unexpectedly.Try again.
Force kill - report

App is upgraded regularly and a fix would be very useful.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).